# crawling through pagination mechanize python

Tags: python, mechanize

I am using mechanize & python to crawl website and get data. So far I am able to submit the form and get the content from that page. But I am unable to trigger click on "Next Page" link and get data. My code is follows:

```
import re
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("http://portal.uspto.gov/EmployeeSearch/")
br.select_form(name="SearchEmployeeDataBean")
br.form['name'] = 'a'
response = br.submit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
table = soup.find_all('table')[16]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
data = [[td.findChildren(text=True) for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]
for a in data:
    if a:
        examiner = " ".join(a[0][1].split())
        phone = a[1][1]
        extension_office = a[3][1]
        office_description = "|".join(re.findall(r'\d+', a[4][1]))
        # print(examiner, phone, extension_office, office_description)
```

Now on results page there is button having text "Next Page >>". I tried it clicking using following code:

Button HTML:

```
<a onclick="javascript:goToPage('currentPage', '3')" href="#">Next Page &gt;&gt;</a>
```

Python Code:

```
req = br.click_link(text_regex='Next Page >>')
r2 = br.open(req)
r2soup = BeautifulSoup(r2)
```

But no success.

Please help me how to click on next button and get data from there till no next page is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in mechanize that it doesn't support javascript. Whenever mechanize reach the page after submit, then javascript not working due to it pagination click was not triggered. I have achieved what I want using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). and Beautiful Soup using following selenium selector:

```
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next Page >>")
elem1.click()
```